# Html5 Canvas Line Join doesn't work with thin lines

Tags: html, html5-canvas

How do I implement round line line for thin (`0.5` or `1` px) lines? Standard `lineJoin` only works for much thicker lines than I actually have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the line to curve at the corner, where the line thickness is less than the radius of the curve, you may want to use [`arcTo`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-arcto) on your current path with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Well, you can, but what a waist of time... Imagine my hyper simplistic drawing has 12 line joins, which will result in 12 asrcs?? harsh..

Comment: Here's the approach which worked for me - create two drawings using a phat line - inner and outer, inner should be slightly smaller and offset by the logical line width. Outer is filled with border color, inner is filled with background color. This way I can still rely on lineJoin functionality and avoid using low level primitives like `arcTo`.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds ok.  If I was having to do a lot of this type of drawing, I'd abstract it into a function that takes the endpoints you want to draw between and work out the arc segments programmatically.